# Using the calendar class in java to get the DAY OF THE WEEK?

Tags: java, debugging, time, calendar

hey i've been trying to get the day of the week by using the Calendar class in java, but it doesn't really seem to work. It's usually off by a day or just really off. Also, 2016 is a leap year, does java know that?  So far here's my code

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance ();
        cal.set(2013 - 1900, 2, 27);
        switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Sun");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Mon");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Tues");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Weds");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Thurs");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Fri");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Sat");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks pls help

Comment: You should use the new `java.time` API instead. It's a lot easier to use and has less surprises than the old API.

Comment: Did you try, say, printing out the value of `cal` to see if your assumptions are correct? Did you carefully read the Javadoc for the `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` classes?  These are fundamental troubleshooting steps that you should learn to perform _before_ asking for help. Basic curiosity and willingness to experiment are the foundatin of being a software developer.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes. Now supplanted by the java.time classes. The `DayOfWeek` enum and its [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) are the key here. Leap year is handled, yes.

The [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method translates the name of the day into any human language specified by a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) such as [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) or [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH).

[`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) determines (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

```
String output = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 2 , 27 ).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```